# Rails vanity URL preventing #edit from working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Users can create and edit stories (basically blogs). I set up a custom vanity URL for the stories, so instead of just the incrementing id, it displays `/stories/1-some-story-title`. That works well for #show, but when I try to edit the story, (which uses the `/stories/1-some-story-title/edit` route) I see an error:

```rb
Routing Error:
No route matches [POST] "/stories/1-some-story-title/edit"
```

However if I try to visit the non-vanity URL manually (`/stories/1/edit`) it works, so it's definitely something with the vanity URL not being looked up in the db properly, I just haven't been able to sort out exactly why yet.

It seems odd to me that Rails can lookup the story without issue for #show, but runs into issues with #edit

It's worth noting that I'm using `Active Admin`, and `Action Text` (Trix) as well.

Any guidance is appreciated. I'm still getting the hang of Rails, so any articles you've found helpful are certainly welcome too.

---

### Stories Controller #show, #edit and #update

```rb
  def show
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    unless @current_user.is_admin?
      redirect_to root_path if @story.created_at < 2.hours.ago
      redirect_to root_path unless @current_user == @story.user
    end
  end

  def update
    @story = Story.find(params[:id])
    if @story.user == @current_user || @current_user.is_admin?
      if @story.update(form_params)
        redirect_to story_path(@story)
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    else
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

---

#### models/story.rb

```
class Story < ApplicationRecord


  # A story can have many comments
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  # A story can have many favourites
  has_many :favourites, dependent: :destroy
  # A story can only belong to one user
  belongs_to :user

  # Add Trix Rich Text Editor
  has_rich_text :body

  # Add image uploader
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :body, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }

  # Changing story URL from number to story title
  def to_param
    id.to_s + '-' + title.parameterize
  end

end
```

---

#### Routes.rb

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Routes for stories
  resources :stories do
    resources :comments
    resource :favourite
  end

  # routes for users
  resources :users
  # Routes for sessions
  resource :session

  # Set homepage as stories index page
  root 'stories#index'

  # Add new pages and their urls
  get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
  get 'our-story', to: 'pages#our_story'
  get 'terms-and-conditions', to: 'pages#terms'

  get 'favourites', to: 'favourites#index'
end
```

---

#### schema.rb

```rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_05_17_183348) do

  create_table "action_text_rich_texts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.text "body"
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.bigint "record_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name"], name: "index_action_text_rich_texts_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource"
  end

  create_table "active_storage_attachments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "record_type", null: false
    t.integer "record_id", null: false
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_on_blob_id"
    t.index ["record_type", "record_id", "name", "blob_id"], name: "index_active_storage_attachments_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_blobs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "key", null: false
    t.string "filename", null: false
    t.string "content_type"
    t.text "metadata"
    t.string "service_name", null: false
    t.bigint "byte_size", null: false
    t.string "checksum", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.index ["key"], name: "index_active_storage_blobs_on_key", unique: true
  end

  create_table "active_storage_variant_records", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "blob_id", null: false
    t.string "variation_digest", null: false
    t.index ["blob_id", "variation_digest"], name: "index_active_storage_variant_records_uniqueness", unique: true
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "body"
    t.integer "story_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["story_id"], name: "index_comments_on_story_id"
  end

  create_table "favourites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "story_id", null: false
    t.integer "user_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["story_id"], name: "index_favourites_on_story_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_favourites_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "url"
    t.string "image"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "stories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "topic"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.string "image"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.string "username"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "password_digest"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.boolean "is_admin", default: false
    t.string "avatar"
  end

  add_foreign_key "active_storage_attachments", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "active_storage_variant_records", "active_storage_blobs", column: "blob_id"
  add_foreign_key "comments", "stories"
  add_foreign_key "favourites", "stories"
  add_foreign_key "favourites", "users"
end
```

Comment: Waaaait a second. The error message says "No route matches [POST] "/stories/1-some-story-title/edit" - why on earth is it a POST request and not a GET request? Whats going on here? Or do you have a form thats sending a POST request to the edit route? Thats all wrong. You modify resources with a PATCH request to the member route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Needed to add:

```
  def to_param
    id.to_s + '-' + title.parameterize
  end
```

to the `app/admin/stories.rb` file. It was already included in the `story.rb` model, but not in the directory for Active Admin.